# Switching between read-only and read-write databases using spring @Transactional and AbstractRoutingDataSource

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I need to use a read-only and read-write data sources using Spring's `@Transactional` annotation. I have the following setup:

```
public class DataSourceRouter extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return DatabaseContextHolder.getEnvironment();
    }
}

@Aspect
public class DataSourceSwitch {
    @Around("@annotation(transactional)")
    public Object proceed(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Transactional transactional) throws Throwable {
        DatabaseEnvironment newEnv = transactional.readOnly() ?
                DatabaseEnvironment.READ_ONLY : DatabaseEnvironment.READ_WRITE;
        DatabaseContextHolder.setEnvironment(newEnv);
        return pjp.proceed();
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class JpaConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource getDataSource() throws Exception {
        DataSourceRouter router = new DataSourceRouter();
        Map<Object, Object> dataSources = new HashMap<>();
        dataSources.put(DatabaseEnvironment.READ_ONLY, <readOnlyDb>);
        dataSources.put(DatabaseEnvironment.READ_WRITE, <readWriteDb>);
        router.setTargetDataSources(dataSources);
        return router;
    }
}
```

Class `DatabaseContextHolder` saves the DB that should be used to a `ThreadLocal`. Methods with the `@Transactional` annotation have the `readOnly` flag set accordingly.

The issue I'm facing is that the method `determineCurrentLookupKey` of the router is called only once when the first `@Transactional` method is called, and is not called again in following transactional methods, which might require a different data source. So for example if the first method called requires a read-only datasource and later another method requires a read-write data source, the DB context does change, but `determineCurrentLookupKey` is not called again and so it tries to write to the read-only database, and fails. Shouldn't the `determineCurrentLookupKey` method be called each time a transactional method is called?

The methods are not called from each other or from the same class. Also adding `propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` to the `@Transactional` annotation didn't help. What's the best way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add this to `application.yaml`:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false
```